# Dynamically added form data not binding on postback .net framework 4.7.2 MCV using EF

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a model that has an array of a dynamic object.  This object simply has a startdatetime, enddatetime and an int for number of slots.

I am using MVC, EF and .net 4.7.2

What I ultimately want to do is allow the user (using js) to add multiple records into a table.  This works!

What is broken is on postback, the array is not binding to the array.

What am I doing wrong?

I have 2 models:

```
  public class testmodel
    {
     

        [Required]
        public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }

        public int? NumberOfSlots { get; set; }
    }

  public class testMainModel
    {
        public List<testmodel> AllDates { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> TestShifts()
        {
            Models.testMainModel model = new Models.testMainModel();

            List<Models.testmodel> testDates = new List<Models.testmodel>();

            model.AllDates = testDates;

            return View(model) ;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> TestShifts(Models.testMainModel model)
        {

            var x = model;

            var y = 1;

            return View(model);
        }
```

View:

```
@model WCSOReserves.Models.testMainModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TestShifts";
}

<h2>TestShifts</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("TestShifts", "Events", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Start Date/Time</th>
                <th>End Date/Time</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="eventDateTimes" data-event-dates-start-count="@(Model.AllDates.Count - 1)">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AllDates.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr data-id="@i">
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.AllDates[i].StartDateTime" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.AllDates[i].EndDateTime" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                            <i class="align-middle me-2 fas fa-fw fa-trash-alt"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="addDateTime">Add Shift</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</div>
}
@section Scripts{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
   
   
    $('button#addDateTime').on('click', function() {
        var countVal = parseInt($('#eventDateTimes').attr('data-event-dates-start-count'));
       
        countVal += 1;

        var inputStartDate = $('<input />').attr('type', 'datetime-local').attr('data-val', 'true')
            .attr('data-val-required', 'The Start Date Field is required.')
            .attr('id', 'testMainModel_AllDates_' + countVal + '__StartDateTime')
            .attr('name', 'testMainModel.AllDates[' + countVal + '].StartDateTime').addClass('form-control');

        var inputEndDate = $('<input />').attr('type', 'datetime-local').attr('data-val', 'true')
            .attr('data-val-required', 'The End Date Field is required.')
            .attr('id', 'testMainModel_AllDates_' + countVal + '__EndDateTime')
            .attr('name', 'testMainModel.AllDates[' + countVal + '].EndDateTime').addClass('form-control');

        var button = $('<button />').attr('type', 'button').addClass('btn btn-sm btn-danger')
            .append($('<i />').addClass('align-middle me-2 fas fa-fw fa-trash-alt'));

        var row = $('<tr />')
            .attr('data-id', countVal)
            .append($('<td />').append(inputStartDate))
            .append($('<td />').append(inputEndDate))
            .append($('<td />').append(button));

        $('#eventDateTimes').append(row);
       
        $('#eventDateTimes').attr('data-event-dates-start-count', countVal);
    });
   
    $(document).on('click',
        '#eventDateTimes tr td button',
        function() {
            $('tr[data-id="' + $(this).parent().parent().attr('data-id') + '"]').remove();
        });

   
});



</script>
```

js works, I can add rows dynamically.  However, on postback, the model is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> js works, I can add rows dynamically. However, on postback, the model is empty.

Not only your postback. You even cannot receive the model in backend which caused postback null model.

Model Binding system binds the property by name attribute. Your frontend name attribute is like `testMainModel.AllDates[index].PropertyName`, which does not match the backend.

A simple way is to change your post action parameter name like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> TestShifts(Models.testMainModel testMainModel)
{

    var x = testMainModel;

    var y = 1;

    return View(testMainModel);
}
```

Another way is that you can change the `name` from `testMainModel.AllDates[index].PropertyName` to `AllDates[index].PropertyName`. In this way you will no need change the action parameter.

```
var inputStartDate = $('<input />').attr('type', 'datetime-local').attr('data-val', 'true')
    .attr('data-val-required', 'The Start Date Field is required.')
    .attr('id', 'testMainModel_AllDates_' + countVal + '__StartDateTime')
    .attr('name', 'AllDates[' + countVal + '].StartDateTime').addClass('form-control');

var inputEndDate = $('<input />').attr('type', 'datetime-local').attr('data-val', 'true')
    .attr('data-val-required', 'The End Date Field is required.')
    .attr('id', 'testMainModel_AllDates_' + countVal + '__EndDateTime')
    .attr('name', 'AllDates[' + countVal + '].EndDateTime').addClass('form-control');
```

Besides, ASP.NET does not have tag helper, **it uses Html Helper**. Tag Helper exists in ASP.NET Core. So if you use ASP.NET, you nee change html code below:

```
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.AllDates[i].StartDateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@type= "datetime-local" } })
</td>
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.AllDates[i].EndDateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "datetime-local" } })

</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `data-event-dates-start-count` should be same as total count.

Try

```
<tbody id="eventDateTimes" data-event-dates-start-count="@(Model.AllDates.Count)">
```

Instead of

```
<tbody id="eventDateTimes" data-event-dates-start-count="@(Model.AllDates.Count - 1)">
```